# C# Exception handling not working on ObjectDataSource

Tags: c#, .net, error-handling, try-catch, objectdatasource

On my C# .NET web application I have a GridView bound to an ObjectDataSource. This ObjectDataSource uses as its select, update, insert, delete commands methods from a .cs file in my App_Code folder. Also on the ObjectDataSource I have OnDeleted, OnUpdated, etc... set up to point to a function in my code-behind that attempts to update a label with the error message so that the user knows the database command didn't work:

```
protected void odsLinks_DBAction(object sender, ObjectDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
    {    
        lbLinksErrorBox.Text = "";
        if (e.Exception != null)
        {
            lbLinksErrorBox.Text = "There was a problem.<br>" + e.Exception.InnerException.Message.ToString();
            lbLinksErrorBox.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            //e.ExceptionHandled = true;
        }
    }
```

Where I actually do my database actions, I have try/catch blocks set up around them like:

```
try
{
    //SQL work happens here
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    //It sends me an email here
}
```

The problem is that when I have an error in my SQL statement, and it lands in the catch block, the error takes over the screen. I'd rather the error show up in my label lbLinksErrorBox as red text so the user is aware of the problem but can keep working.

It doesn't seem like the onDeleted error handling is ever being reached. The error ends at the try/catch block and never makes it to the onDeleted odsLinks_DBAction function in my code-behind.

This is what my ObjectDataSource looks like in my .aspx page:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsLinks" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetLinks" TypeName="TaskDataAccess" DeleteMethod="DeleteLink" InsertMethod="AddLink" UpdateMethod="UpdateLink" OnDeleted="odsLinks_DBAction" OnInserted="odsLinks_DBAction" OnUpdated="odsLinks_DBAction">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="link_ID" Type="String" />
        </DeleteParameters>
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="hfTreeID" Name="tree_ID" PropertyName="Value" Type="String" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="hfTaskID" Name="task_ID" PropertyName="Value" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="link_Title" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="link_URL" Type="String" />
        </InsertParameters>
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="hfTreeID" Name="tree_ID" PropertyName="Value" Type="String" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="hfTaskID" Name="task_ID" PropertyName="Value" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="link_ID" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="link_Title" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="link_URL" Type="String" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Here is an example of how my App_Code .cs file database connection is set up:

```
public static void DeleteLink(string link_ID)
{
    GetUserDateTime gudt = new GetUserDateTime();
    try
    {
        string dsn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myDatabaseHere"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(dsn);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE [TreeLinks] SET Link_Deleted = 'YES' where Link_ID = @Link_ID", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Link_ID", link_ID);

        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        string body = "Error on TaskDataAccess.DeleteLink() <br>" + gudt.user + "<br>" + e.ToString();
        SendEmail.sendEmail("Error on Task page", body);
    }
}
```

Ideas? How can I get the error from my SQL connection to not take over the whole page but instead show up in a label on my webpage?

Answer (score 0):

Your events will never fire as the exception will be thrown before they are triggered.

Set your label with the exception information from within the catch.

Ok, its been a very while since I used web forms but if IIRC on your ods you need to add a callback method called when the appcode event finished, eg. OnUpdating="MyObjectDataSource_Updated"...

The MyObjectDataSource_Updated method should be in your page not the shared cs file, and as such it will have access to your page elements (label etc.)

Comment: I have it in the db class code so that it can be shared across other pages

Comment: No, I mean move the try catch to your page, leave the db code where it is, the exception can then be raised in your page and you can access the error there and assign it to your label.

Comment: I'm not sure where to place the try/catch in my page since all it is is an ObjectDataSource pointing to the update/delete/etc method like this:

Comment: <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsLinks" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetLinks" TypeName="TaskDataAccess" DeleteMethod="DeleteLink">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="link_ID" Type="String" />
        </DeleteParameters>
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>

Comment: So, re-reading this on my laptop - you havent wired up the callback method 'odsLinks_DBAction' in your aspx. Each action should have the db (shared) code, and then a callback in your page's codebehind.

Comment: I currently have onUpdated, onDeleted, etc set up in my object data source.  They all point to "odsLinks_DBAction" in my code-behind.  I didn't see the need to have several identical methods in my code-behind that just handled errors from the app_code database attempts.  Am I supposed to be using onUpdating instead of onUpdated? When I read the description of onUpdating it sounded like that was triggered before the update command was attempted. Maybe I read it wrong.

Comment: Could you provide some more details on this: "you havent wired up the callback method 'odsLinks_DBAction' in your aspx. Each action should have the db (shared) code, and then a callback in your page's codebehind" ?  I looked at the msdn example but it already looks similar to what I have set up.

Comment: In your definition for the objectdatasource you don't have the events for OnUpdated, OnDeleted etc defined contrary to your comment saying you do.

Comment: I've updated my initial post up at the top to include exactly how my object data source looks on the .aspx page.  OnDeleted, OnInserted and OnUpdated all point to odsLinks_DBAction in my code-behind file.  The code for odsLinks_DBAction is also posted up top.

Comment: So I would think there's an exception in your catch block, where you send your email.

Comment: There is.  And the email is sent properly inside the catch block in my cs app_code file.  But the exception isn't making it to the odsLinks_DBAction method in my code-behind.  Is there something different I need to do in the catch block in the app_code cs file?

Comment: No, I said an exception WITHIN your CATCH block (not just in the try).
What is the exception being thrown? Can you show your actual code.

Comment: I added an example method (DeleteLink) from my app_code .cs file in the original post message.

Comment: And what is the exception? 
btw, you would be better off using e.Message and obtaining the stack trace rather than just e.ToString()

Comment: Do I need to specifically say something like "throw new ...." ?
For testing I have induced an error by misspelling the column name in my query (I changed Link_ID to link_ID in the WHERE clause).  This results in the following:

Comment: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid column name 'link_ID'. at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, .... it goes on from here

Comment: So can you try commenting out the try catch in your database method and let the exception bubble up to the code-behind.

Comment: When I do that, the webpage is taken over with the error (and I don't get the email obviously).  The exception still isn't making it to the code-behind to get handled by the onDeleted function.  The screen shows "Server Error in /myApplicationName. Invalid column name 'link_ID'. Description: an unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace...  Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'link_ID' "  line 203

Comment: In your web config, what does your <customErrors /> tag look like?

Comment: I don't have a customErrors section set up in web.config

Comment: Add one, set to "On".

Comment: Actually, a better approach would be to fix your deliberate sql error, if you still cant hit your code behind method youll know it is simply incorrectly wired up.

Comment: Also, can you got F12 in your browser to view the console, do you have any errors reported when the event should be firing?

Answer (score 0):

Add the event handlers for OnUpdated, OnDeleted etc to your objectdatasource definition, these should point to methods in your code behind so they have access to both the exception in the eventargs and the label element which you want to display exception information in.